# Problems with gradle sync after adding 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am need to add `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'` to my gradle module app file. I changed minSdkVersion 15 to 16. and when I sync gradle I get this error when I hover over `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions `25.3.1, 25.0.0, 23.4.0.` Examples `include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1` and `com.android.support:design:25.0.0` less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

I don't understand where the 23.4.0 version is found or whatever is needed to fix this here is the gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.*********.firebasechat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is build.gradle(Project: FirebaseChat)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: main gradle file please

Answer (score 0):

first Refresh The Whole project,and then goto **Build > Clean  project**, next agin goto **Build>Rebuild**

Second check Android sdk manager for updates,if updates available please update it.
Now go to **app/build.gradle** file

remove this line

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

after that Click Sync

i hope this will work.